# Value out of range exception when setting a string member of INetFwRule

Tags: c#, exception, firewall

I'm trying to add a firewall rule for TCP Port 1433, with a specific group using the NetFwTypeLib library.
But adding the port into the LocalPorts variable as integer converted into a string or just as a simple "1433" string, returns a Value out of range exception.
Removing the port and just using all ports works fine.

Here is the code I used:

```
bool CreateRule(string sName, string sPort, NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ ProtocolType, string sIpAdress, string sGroup = "")
{
    try
    {
        INetFwRule firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));

        firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
        firewallRule.Description = "Used to allow Server access.";
        firewallRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
        firewallRule.Enabled = true;
        firewallRule.Name = sName;
        firewallRule.Grouping = sGroup;
        firewallRule.LocalPorts = sPort; // "1433" causes out of range exception
        firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = sIpAdress;
        firewallRule.Protocol = (int)ProtocolType;

        INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(
            Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
        firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);

        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Setting the `firewallRule.LocalPorts` member causes the exception.
Does someone have an idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to put the Protocol type before the Port, so it is valid.

Comment: can confirm. 
In PoSH if you 
`$rule = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWRule`
you'll get an exception if you try to assign `$rule.LocalPorts` before you assign `$rule.Protocol`

Comment: In addition, if protocol is set to "any" ports will not be allowed.